# npm Command No response

Tags: node.js, npm

![npm -v can work,but npm --help or other commond has no responses][1]

```
os:windos8,npm2.11.2,nodev0.12.6.

path =C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm;E:\nodejs\;
```

`npm -v` can work, but `npm --help` or other commands have no responses. Can someone tell me what should I do?

Comment: Same issue here on Win7x64 even if everything "works"

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling npm?

Comment: I hava uninstalling and reinstalling nodejs,

Answer (score 0):

I used `npm config set prefix`command make a .npmrc swells configuration file in the current directory, change the configuration file in turmoil, every uninstall reinstall will not delete the configuration file. deleting this file.everything is ok.